# Shoud I close the Stream in WCF REST Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, azure, stream

I have some WCF Rest Service with server side method and stream variable which is passed to it.

My question is: Should I close stream after saving file locally?

```
void ImportFile(Stream stream)
{
    // Reading stream...
    stream.Close(); // ??? is it really needed ???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT depends on the origin of the stream. If it is a stream you've created then Coder1409's answer is correct - you should wrap the stream creation statement in a using command. If however, since you specifically mention you are in a Rest Service, the stream is an HTTP request stream, it is a forward-only read-only stream and it's lifetime will be governed by the HTTP Context you got it from.

Comment: Stream is coming from rest client. I am not sure if its request stream.

Comment: If an outside entity (outside your immediate code) passes you a stream and you do not provide a flag in your method for the passer to indicate if they want the stream closed on return, it is probably a good idea not to close the stream. Allow the passing entity to control the lifetime of the stream which it created and passed to you. Arbitrarily closing a stream that your code did not create is bad form, you don't know if the caller needs the stream to remain open for future calls.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the using statement which will dispose of your stream when you're done with it like

using (stream)
{

//code here

}